# Secret Id and client token rotation in Hashicorp vault

Tags: spring, hashicorp-vault, spring-cloud-vault-config

I am using `approle` authentication type which takes in `role-id` and `secret-id` along with `root token` in the header to generate a `client token` which can further be used as an `auth token` in the header to create and retrieve secrets. This is what happens internally when using spring cloud vault I guess. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Now, I need to rotate my secret-id for every 30 days and the client token for every 24 hours. How do I achieve this? Does spring cloud vault provides an inbuilt library to do this? If not where should I make the changes?

Comment: You can set TTL for both of those.

Comment: @MattSchuchard, how do I rotate the auth token? since I don't have direct access to the token which is generated by the spring cloud vault library.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do the equivalent of a `vault write -f auth/approle/role/my-role/secret-id` to get a new secret id. Where you do this is where it gets interesting...

I assume you already have a Vault policy that allows you to [generate a new secret_id](https://www.vaultproject.io/api-docs/auth/approle#generate-new-secret-id). Make sure that the `role_name` parameter is fixed to your application current role. Chances are you will want to limit the metadata, too.

I would suggest this pattern:

1. Something (a pipeline or scheduled job of some kind) creates the new secret-id. Bonus points if it is wrapped and single use, but let's save that for another question.
2. That something will store the secret-id in a secure place. Could be in the Vault KV **version 2** store where the application can read.
3. After creating the new secret-id, that something lists the secrets and keeps the N most recent secret ids. Say the last 5. This makes the process asynchronous and allows running applications to keep going.

Now in your application, you must have a periodic task that looks up the latest secret id and reauthenticates to Vault with it.

If possible, I would suggest that you avoid the problem altogether and use the authentication method provided the platform your are on, it Vault supports it, like [GCP](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/gcp), [AWS](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/aws) or [Kubernetes](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/kubernetes).